# Sorted List of folders (by size) of an specific user

Tags: unix, command

I need a command to get a list of all folders owned by a specific user.

Is there a way to get them sorted by size and in addition with the total sum of all sizes?

My recent try was:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter user: " username

for folder in $(find /path/ -maxdepth 4 -user $username) ; do
        du -sh $folder | sort -hr
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code of your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (version 1, incomplete, see version 2 below!)

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp_du=$(mktemp)
path="/path"

find "$path" -maxdepth 4 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' directory
do
    du -sh "$directory" >>"$tmp_du"
done

sort -hr "$tmp_du"

echo ""
echo "TOTAL"
du -sh "$path"

rm -f "$tmp_du"
```

- The `find` with `-print0` is explained here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- Since you want the size of each directory, you have to store all the results in a file, then sort it.

---

**Version 2** with the -user which I forgot in my first answer, plus a total that takes into account only the directories for that user:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Enter user: " username

tmp_du=$(mktemp)
path="/path"

# Get a list of directories owned by "$username", and their size, store it in a file
find "$path" -maxdepth 4 -type d -user "$username" -exec du -s {} \; 2>/dev/null | sort -n >"$tmp_du"

# Add the first column of that file
sum=$( awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print sum; }' "$tmp_du" )

# Output, must output first column in human readable format
numfmt --field=1 --to=iec <"$tmp_du"

# Output total
echo "Total: $(echo "$sum" | numfmt --to=iec)"

rm -f "$tmp_du"
```

- here all the directory sizes are stored in a file
- the total is the sum of the first column
- to output the numbers in a format similar to -h of du, use numfmt.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the part with the username and it works great. The only deficit is that I don't want the total space of $path but only the sum of the folders of the user.